# Pinax : Add new tab to the basic_projects application : Confused by documentation

Tags: django, pinax

Just cloned the basic_project and trying to customize by following this - http://pinaxproject.com/docs/0.7/tabs/#ref-tabs

Created a new app "myapp", added the new tab to the right_nav and edited the "site_tabs.css" as well.
However when I click on the tab, although the page does change to myapp, the background color of the tab doesn't change.

This line in the documentation - `Create a myapps/base.html template that all pages under that tab will extend. Make sure it defines a block body_class with content myapp` is confusing me.

What is that `"body_class" with content myapp` ?, is it some "div" with the class having "{% block body_class%}" ?

My code of the myapp page is pretty simple right now -

`{% extends "site_base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}

{% load ifsetting_tag %}

{% block head_title %}

{% trans "Custom App page" %}

{% endblock %}`

`< div class="myapp">

< h1 >

{% trans "Custom App page" %}</h1>

{% if user.is_authenticated %}

< p >You are signed in !!</p>

{% else %}

< p >You are NOT signed in !!</p>

{% endif %}

< /div >`

The site_base.css is as follows -

`body.profile #tab_profile a,

body.myapp #tab_myapp a,

body.notices #tab_notices a

{

    color: #000; /* selected tab text colour */

}`

`body.profile #tab_profile,

body.myapp #tab_myapp,

body.notices #tab_notices

{

    margin: 0; /* to compensate for border */

    padding: 5px 0 5px;

    background-color: #DEF; /* selected tab colour */

    border-left: 1px solid #000; /* tab border */

    border-top: 1px solid #000; /* tab border */

    border-right: 1px solid #000; /* tab border */

}`

Any pointers would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What do your site_base.html and site_tabs.css look like?

Comment: The site_base.html is the default from pinax version 0.7.3. Adding the site_tabs.css in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a block named `body_class` inside your `site_base.html` with the content `myapp` like this:

```
{% block body_class %}myapp{% endblock %}
```

This will override the block defined in `base.html`.

```
<body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}">
```

It is probably used to by CSS to make your tab active. See the example at the bottom of the documentation.

```
body.profile #tab_profile a,
body.blogs #tab_blogs a,
body.bookmarks #tab_bookmarks a
{
    color: #000; /* selected tab text colour */
}
```

Now, if you're opening pages that use your template, the body tag looks like this:

```
<body class="myapp">
```

Therefore the CSS selector above can match for your tab.

```
body.myapp #tab_myapp a { // active
```

Comment: Great ! that worked. And to override the content, I use the "{% block body %}" in the myapp_base.html ?

Comment: @PlanetUnknown Can't find it in the docs, but according to the base template, `body` seems to be the right block.

Comment: I tried to find the very base html and found it in the pinax/templates/default/ directory with name as base.html. It has this block - {% block body %}{% endblock %} and it translates to <div id="body"> when rendered. Hence to fill the body segment of a page, I have to override it in the pages under myapp. Just tried it and worked 8-)

Comment: @PlanetUnknown so, am I suppose to write {% block body %} in myapp.html? Thanks.